# Rails 3 creates duplicate form object for nested records when updating them

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

There are two models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validate_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :category_id
end
```

And a form for category

```
<%= simple_form_for @category do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |p| %>
      <%= render :partial => "product_fields", :locals => { :f => p } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see there is a uniqueness validation which makes sure that products are uniq within category. The problem starts when validation is not passed.

Calling `@category.update_attributes(params[:category])` results in duplicate form object. When rendering the form with errors rails creates additional associated product with the id of duplicate record but different name.

For example:

Given we have two products within category: Bread and Butter. If set Butter to Bread when editing a category's products a new form object will be created and the form will be rendered with Bread, Butter, Bread, saying last entry has a duplicate name.
How can i prevent rails from creating those duplicate records? I'm using rails 3.2.11 if it matters.